# Bash colors defined in .bashrc behaving oddly. I can't figure it out

Tags: bash, colors, bashrc

When I type `ls -l` my command color defined in `.bashrc` is only used on the first item up until the directory or file name which has its own color defined.  The proceeding lines seem to get a default white color.

My command line color is defined at the end of my PS1 as 01;33

I highlighted the problem in this image..

[image: problem highlighted]

Here is the `.bashrc` file

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;37m\]\u@\h:\w\$\[\033[01;33m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

#LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;33:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem descripton

That's the wrong way of setting colours for `ls`.  `ls` uses the terminal colours the same way that the prompt does.  When `dev` is colored brown by `ls` it happens in a similar fashion to this:

```
\[\033[0;33\]dev\[\033[0m\]
```

And the terminal colour is switched back to the *regular colour* (`\[\033[0m\]`).  From there on the regular colour is used to display the text, until `Documents` when it is switched to brown and back to regular again.

Basically, it is a bad idea to have a prompt that leaves a terminal colour switched on:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;37m\]\u@\h:\w\$\[\033[01;33m\] '
```

Instead you should *always* switch the colour back to regular:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;37m\]\u@\h:\w\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

And then use `LS_COLORS` environment variable to change the way `ls` prints colours.

---

#### Hack

`ls` is aliased to as:

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```

On most linux distros today.  Removing that alias is one way to get your hacky prompt to work with `ls`.  But that is not a good solution, and you will likely suffer problems with other programs.

---

#### Proper solution

If you really want to change the default colour of the text in the terminal you should configure it in the terminal emulator itself.  Pretty much all terminal emulators (`gnome-terminal`, `xfce-terminal`, `kterm`) have a configuration section where the default (regular) colour can be set.

In `xterm` and `rxvt` variants the default colour can be set in `~/.Xresources`.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try and implement your "proper solution".  I had a feeling leaving the trailing color on PS1 wasn't quite right.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After each line output, the `ls` command will reset the color.  If you run `dircolors -p` you'll see a line

```
RESET 0 # reset to "normal" color
```

If you run `dircolors` on its own (which will output in `LS_COLORS` format) then you'll see 'rs=0'.   So if you want `ls` to reset to a different color then you'll need to set up a custom `LS_COLORS` variable with `rs=01;33` in it and export that variable.  Now `ls` will reset to your custom color at the end of each line.